# Second Order Partial Differential Equation with Constant Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering if I could ask a question regarding second order PDE.
It is from a mass transfer problem, but I have difficulties with mathematics here.

So, the equation I have at hand is $$Ax_{zz} + Bx_{z} = x_{t}$$

Boundary conditions and initial condition are as following:

\begin{align}
x(0,t) &= x_{1} \\
x(h,t) &= x_{2} \\
x(z,0) &= 0
\end{align}

$A, B$, and $h$ are all constants.

Thank you :)

Comment: I have tried separation of variables, but it becomes way too messy

Comment: If you are finding this PDE difficult to apply separation of variables to, making the change of variable $x(z, t) = y(z + Bt, t) = y(w, t)$ transforms the PDE into $$y_{t} = A y_{ww}$$ which is the heat equation. You can then transform the data and solve using a separation of variables that is 'easier' to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of Variables is indeed quite a mess, but I suspect it is still the most straightforward way of solving a Boundary Value Problem such as this.

$$Ax_{zz}+Bx_z=x_t$$

Suppose $x=Z(z)T(t)$. We can substitute into the PDE:

$$AZ''T+BZ'T=ZT'$$

$$\frac{AZ''+BZ'}Z=\frac{T'}T$$

The left hand side is independent of $t$, and the right is independent of $z$, so both must be equal to a constant, which I'll refer to as $k$. From this, we may derive 2 ODEs:

$$AZ''+BZ'-kZ=0$$

$$T'-kT=0$$

Both of these ODEs are linear and homogeneous, so finding their respective solution sets should be relatively straightforward. We can start with the $t$ equation, which yields a simple solution set.

$$T=ce^{kt}$$

The $z$ equation is a bit more nuanced. I'll use $\gamma_+$ and $\gamma_-$ to represent the roots of the characteristic equation for $Z$:

$$\gamma_\pm=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2+4Ak}}{2A}$$

This allows us to write the solution set compactly:

$$Z=ae^{\gamma_+z}+be^{\gamma_-z}$$

From here it's just a matter of imposing boundary conditions, which in this problem is a bit more tricky than something like the Heat Equation. To do this, we can abuse the fact that this equation is linear. Suppose we have a solution to the PDE $\psi_1$ which is equal to a function $\beta_1$ on the boundaries. Likewise, another solution $\psi_2$ is equal to $\beta_2$ on the boundaris. From the linearity of the PDE, we can conclude that the linear combination $a\psi_1+b\psi_2$ is also a solution, and is equal to $a\beta_1+a\beta_2$ on the boundaries. This allows us to build our boundary conditions out of other sets of boundary conditions that are easier to handle mathematically.

To begin we can consider a particular solution $x_p$ such that $x_p(0,t)=x_1$, $x_p(h,t)=x_2$, and $x_p$ is independent of $t$. We see that we must choose $k=0$ to eliminate the $t$ dependence, which narrows down the solution.

$$x_p=ZT=a+be^{-\frac BA z}$$

The remaining boundary conditions give us a system of equations for $a$ and $b$.

$$a+b=x_1,\ \ \ a+be^{-\frac BA h}=x_2$$

$$a=x_2-x_1e^{-\frac BA h},\ \ \ b=\frac{x_1-x_2}{1-e^{-\frac BA h}}$$

$$x_p=x_2-x_1e^{-\frac BA h}+\frac{x_1-x_2}{1-e^{-\frac BA h}}e^{-\frac BA z}$$

This particular solution satisfies all of the boundary conditions except $x(0,t)=0$, so we can construct a new set of boundary conditions which, when summed with $x_p$, will give us the boundary values we want. That is:

$$x_h(0,t)=0,\ \ x_h(h,t)=0,\ \ x_h(z,0)=-x_p(z)$$

Here we'll want to use the complex values of $\gamma$, so let $\tau$ and $\omega$ be the real and imaginary parts of $\gamma$ respectively.

$$\tau=\frac{-B}{2A},\ \ \ \omega=\sqrt{-\frac kA-\frac{B^2}{2A^2}}$$

We can then write the $Z$ as a sinusoidal function.

$$Z=ae^{\tau z}sin(\omega z)+be^{\tau z}cos(\omega z)$$

Imposing the new boundary conditions, the cosine term disappears, and only solutions for which $\omega h=\pi n, n\in \mathbb N$ survive,which also fixes $k$. This gives us a set of eigenfunctions for the new boundary conditions, which I'll call $\nu_n$.

$$\nu_n=e^{\tau z+kt}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}h\right),\ \ \ k=-\frac{n^2\pi^2A}{h^2}-\frac{B^2}{2A},\ \ \ n\in\mathbb N$$

We can therefore express $x_h$ as a linear combination of these eigenfunctions.

$$x_h=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\nu_n$$

$a_n$ can be determined using a projection operator $a_n=\frac{<-x_p,\nu_n>}{<\nu_n,\nu_n>}$, where $<,>$ indicates an inner product under which the eigenfunctions are orthogonal. Here we can add an exponential factor to make the inner product equivalent to the Fourier Sine Series for this type of boundary.

$$<f,g>=\int_0^he^{-2\tau z}f(z,0)g(z,0)dz$$

It can be shown by evaluating the integrals that our eigenfunctions are orthogonal under this product, giving us the following expression for $a_n$.

$$a_n=\frac{\int_0^he^{-\tau z}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}h\right)(-x_p(z,0))\ dz}{\int_0^h\sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi z}h\right)dz}=-\frac 2h \int_0^he^{-\tau z}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}h\right)x_p(z,0)\ dz$$

Combining all of this together, we can express the solution $x$ as the sum of $x_p$ and $x_h$, putting everything in terms of $\tau = -\frac B{2A}$ and $k=-\frac{n^2\pi^2A}{h^2}-\frac{B^2}{2A}$.

$$x=x_p+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{\tau z+kt}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}h\right)$$

$$x_p=x_2-x_1e^{2\tau h}+\frac{x_1-x_2}{1-e^{2\tau h}}e^{2\tau z}$$

$$a_n=-\frac 2h \int_0^he^{-\tau z}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}h\right)x_p(z,0)\ dz$$

It is not impossible that this solution can be simplified to a closed from, but this is as far as I've been able to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! Let me first try it your way and I will get back to you if I run into further troubles!